# How to make navbar active link colour change on different pages

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I'm a beginner here, I've got what I believe is a simple problem which I don't know how to solve. Basically i'm making a responsive website, my problem right now is that I can't make my navbar correctly responsive on the other parts of the websites besides my index.html (which works fine).

I've used the code from w3schools in order to create my navbar.

https://www.w3schools.com/howto/tryit.asp?filename=tryhow_js_topnav

As I said it works on my index file. But when I'm on my "news page" It doesn't work correctly. It rezises itself but it says Home on the navbar to the left. How do I make it so that it says news on the news page, starts off news and not the home page? (And for Contact, About aswell) Much thanks! Sorry if this was a stupid question. This is my first time trying to make a responsive website!

Here is the code aswell (from the link at w3 schools):

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<style>
body {margin:0;}

.topnav {
  overflow: hidden;
  background-color: #333;
}

.topnav a {
  float: left;
  display: block;
  color: #f2f2f2;
  text-align: center;
  padding: 14px 16px;
  text-decoration: none;
  font-size: 17px;
}

.topnav a:hover {
  background-color: #ddd;
  color: black;
}

.active {
  background-color: #4CAF50;
  color: white;
}

.topnav .icon {
  display: none;
}

@media screen and (max-width: 600px) {
  .topnav a:not(:first-child) {display: none;}
  .topnav a.icon {
    float: right;
    display: block;
  }
}

@media screen and (max-width: 600px) {
  .topnav.responsive {position: relative;}
  .topnav.responsive .icon {
    position: absolute;
    right: 0;
    top: 0;
  }
  .topnav.responsive a {
    float: none;
    display: block;
    text-align: left;
  }

}
</style>
</head>
<body>

<div class="topnav" id="myTopnav">
  <a href="#home" class="active">Home</a>
  <a href="#news">News</a>
  <a href="#contact">Contact</a>
  <a href="#about">About</a>
  <a href="javascript:void(0);" style="font-size:15px;" class="icon" onclick="myFunction()">&#9776;</a>
</div>

<div style="padding-left:16px">
  <h2>Responsive Topnav Example</h2>
  <p>Resize the browser window to see how it works.</p>
</div>

<script>
function myFunction() {
    var x = document.getElementById("myTopnav");
    if (x.className === "topnav") {
        x.className += " responsive";
    } else {
        x.className = "topnav";
    }
}
</script>

</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 1):

**Reason why it doesn't seem like you're navigating to another page:**

When you click on the link "News", it does not bring you to a new page because of `#news` in this anchor tag `<a href="#news">News</a>`. The hashtag `#` within the `href` specifies a HTML element id where the window would be scrolled to. In your case, it just scrolls to the top of your webpage since there aren't any HTML elements with `id="news"` around. So, this whole time, you were actually just on the one and only page - the "Home" page.

**How to make "News" highlighted when you're on the "News" page:**

1. **Duplicate** the `index.html` you've created and rename it to `news.html`. Make sure that these 2 files are in the same folder. We're going to make it such that each `.html` file represents a page on your website because each page contains unique content and so different HTML code is needed.
2. **Replace these 2 lines** in your code block for each of the files `index.html` and `news.html`:

```html
<a href="#home" class="active">Home</a>
<a href="#news">News</a>
```

with this in `index.html`:

```
  <a href="index.html" class="active">Home</a>
  <a href="news.html">News</a>
```

And with this in `news.html`:

```
  <a href="index.html">Home</a>
  <a href="news.html" class="active">News</a>
```

Here, notice that `class="active"` is now placed on the "Home" link when you're on the "Home" page, i.e. `index.html` and `class="active"` is placed on the "News" link when you're on the "News" page, i.e. `news.html`. This is what gives the link the green highlight (which is according to your specified CSS class .active).

3. **Open** `index.html` in your browser and try clicking on the "News" link. You should be navigated to your "News" page and the navbar should now be highlighted in green like this:

[image: Result of navbar with "News" link highlighted in green]

And when you resize the screen to a smaller size, and click on the hamburger menu button, it should look like this on the "News" page with the correct link highlighted in green:

[image: Result of navbar with "News" link highlighted in green on mobile]

4. **Repeat** for all the other pages.

---

**Tip:**
Copying & pasting your CSS styles in every one of your HTML pages is tedious and contains too much duplicate code. To clean this up, I suggest you put all your CSS styles in one `.css` file and link that file to each of your HTML files instead. Follow the instructions in the "External CSS" section from w3schools [here](https://www.w3schools.com/html/html_css.asp) to do so.

Comment: If this or any answer has solved your question, please consider accepting it by clicking on the check-mark! This indicates to the wider community that you've found a possible solution and for further references :)